# Change database connection in Heroku at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, database-connection

I'd like to be able to change my database connection on a Heroku app at runtime.

Say, for example, have a switch on the web page that lets QA testers change between development and production databases.

[connection_ninja](https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja) seems like a great way to start, but I'm unclear on whether this could work, considering Heroku uses `DATABASE_URL` for whatever reason and overwrites the `database.yml` file.

The other aspect I'm not clear about, is where to establish the connection and how to pass it the argument indicating the database, preferably without having to change my existing code (i.e. inherit from a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`).

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Should you really want to do this, you could use the Heroku API to change the `DATABASE_URL` config variable in your application and then trigger a restart but I would strongly recommend just having seperate Heroku apps running development and production - if production data was changed/deleted then all sorts of trouble would follow I'd guess.

Comment: I actually do have multiple Heroku apps, but it's often annoying since my team changes the configurations quite often to test against both databases. This is mostly due to the performance differences between them. I'm also not particularly worried about production data, since most data access through the web app is read-only.